# Contract.deployed() does not work as expected

Tags: contract-development, truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-test

I use Truffle to test a contract. When i use Contract.deployed() and i fetch address, for example :

- In a first test, the contract's address is
  0x07D899846146b3503dE9D9Dc36B94C2e428eA434
- In a second one, the contract's address is
  0xF79f3B32b78ebD07B2E661b52e9CF374e311f1d5

Another problem is that it seems that on each time i test the contract, it's state is reinitialized.

It seems that `Contract.deployed()` create works like `Contract.new()`, it create a new instance of the contract for each test.

Which can cause this problem ?

Comment: When `truffle test` completes, the next time you run it, the initial migration takes place again and new contracts are deployed. If you've left Ganache opened from the previous execution of `truffle test`, then those new instances will be deployed at different addresses.

Comment: So how can I make sure that the contract is always at the same address? 
How can I test the contract once, a second time by making sure that the state of the contract during the second test is the same as the state of the contract at the end of the first test?

Answer (score 2):

Actually many similar questions of mine not answered yet (even at official forum of truffle 80% questions not addressed ), which clearly indicates that either truffle developers have lost control over project means patching one side creating problem on other side, or they leave this project as Orphan, so don't expect any logical clear answer for your question, I asked question on many places for simple one no one addressed to the point, some one tried but talking here and there but not to the point, so I hope this will be he perfect answer for your question, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When writing tests for Truffle you use `contract()` function. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#use-contract-instead-of-describe-), this function re-runs your migrations script and `Contract.deployed()` returns the instance of the contract deployed during the migration.

You can use `beforeEach()` and deploy new contract there (may be adding some initialization transactions). This way is more explicit and clear, you always see whether you use redeployed contract or the used one.

You do not need to always have the same contract address for the tests as you can use instance of the contract returned by these functions and if you need the contract address you can access it via (probably) `instance.address` or smth like that. See the `truffle-contract` [documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/truffle-contract) for more details.